# Referencing functions and variables through POST

Tags: php

I am currently working on a PHP library with many files. Inside this library are various `require_once(path)` calls, which references variables of different files within this library. This causes some confusion as:

1. This library has little to no comments
2. This library calls different variables and functions within other files, and it can be hard to find out what the function or variable call is doing without manually opening the `require_once()` path to check what the code is doing.

How do I conveniently check where/what the variable and function call is while developing for PHP?

Comment: Thanks. I come from a Java/C# background, so finding out where the function or variable call is is easy (not to add, everything needs to be instantiated *somewhere*, so you can just check where the class or object is instantiated). PHP just seems to.. throw everything at you at once.

Comment: is they anwer posted my centril give you any help??

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 Why don't you try it out yourself? What works for me may not work for you.

Comment: you are right but i dont have ide i nose notpad. but ide are good i will use them i am new Thanks take care

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using a PHP IDE with support for **debugging** and using breakpoints & whatnot.

PHPStorm is a good IDE: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LUTolQw8K9A
http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/php-debugging-session.html

**Dependency on the IDE?** Not if you use git as version control and ignore the IDE specific parts in **.gitignore**. Using composer as your dependency manager and perhaps **Vagrant** for getting the same build environment for everyone can help.

**Breakpoints?** Normally, when developing non-server-based apps with languages such as Java or C++, you will typically use an IDE that allows you to specify points in the code called "breakpoints" which when reached stops the execution of the program and lets you step through the code... It is possible to do the same for PHP webapps with the right tools.

Another method is being intent on testing everything using **unit tests** with tools such as **PHPUnit**. You can always do **spying** and see what **interactions** functions/methods have with other methods/functions. Take a look at: http://blog.lyte.id.au/2014/03/01/spying-with-phpunit/ & https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html
If the parts are guaranteed to work in isolation, so should the whole - given that your glue pieces are correctly configured.

Comment: can you explain bit more. what do you mean by breakpoints and whatnot Thanks

Comment: Would this mess up my development environment? I currently use Sublime Text 2 which adds little to no residual files to my existing projects.

Comment: Assuming that you are using git for version control (which you should) you can easily ignore any IDE related file in your .gitignore, and there are ready made .gitignores on github and other places to just copy. You should also be using composer (dependency management) and tools such as Vagrant to setup your environment in a reproducable fashion in any case... Do a search for "vagrant capistrano".

Comment: i remember checking it and upvoting forget about it +1; now its late